# Get timing on individual queries in Anonymous code block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a set of queries that I need to run in succession, carrying the result from the previous query into the next. My only need is the execution time on the last query in the list, but `SET TIMING ON` gives me the execution time for the whole block. Any idea how to get the time of JUST the last query? The beef is that I don't want the previous queries to interfere with the timing it gives me. Example below:

```
set echo on;
set feedback on;
set timing on;
set serveroutput on;

declare
  pid varchar(20);
  aid varchar(20);
  bob char(1);
begin

  select st.some_id, st.person_id into aid, pid
    from some_table st
      join person p on st.person_id = p.person_id
    where p.name not like '%bob%' and rownum = 1;

  -- get timing of another query here

end;
```

When I run this it gives me the total execution time of the code block:

```
Elapsed: 00:00:00.045
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save [`sysdate`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions191.htm#SQLRF06124) or [`systimestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions192.htm#SQLRF06125) into a pl/sql variable just before the query then use [`dbms_output.put_line`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_output.htm#i1000105) to output the difference afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do what you need to do the way that *Jack Douglas* suggested. But if you really want to go fancy, you coud query `elapsed_time` and divide it by the number of `execution`s of the query, so you get the average execution time for a query.

With the following function...

```
create or replace 
procedure previous_sql_stats (
            ela in out number,
            exe in out number
) as
begin

    select
      s.elapsed_time,
      s.executions
    into
      ela,
      exe
    from
      v$sql      s join
      v$session  t on s.hash_value = t.prev_hash_value and
                      s.address    = t.prev_sql_addr
    where 
      t.audsid=sys_context('userenv','SESSIONID');

end previous_sql_stats;
/
```

... you can get these figures like so:

```
declare
  dummy number;

  ela   number;
  exe   number;

begin

  select 
    avg(sysdate - a.created) into dummy
  from
    dba_objects a cross join
    dba_objects b
  where
    rownum < 1e6;


  previous_sql_stats(ela, exe);

  dbms_output.put_line(
      'total elapsed time: '         || round(ela/1e6,2) || 
      ' seconds, total exectuions: ' || exe || 
      ', per execution: '            || round(ela/exe/1e6,2) || 
      ' seconds');

end;
/
```